# QGIS 2.2 crashes when saving digitized data in ArcSDE 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, qgis-2.2

I am using QGIS 2.2 with ArcSDE 10.1 for Oracle 11gR2
I have created a polygon feature class with SDO_geometry, when trying to save the digitized data QGIS crashes. Please help, I want to edit the ArcSDE data in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If QGIS crashes, this warrants a bug report in any case. Please attach any information that might be useful.

Please open a [bug report](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index#bugs-features-and-issues.html), consider creating a pull request or funding somebody to implement this.